# How to use len(dictionary) inside a for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a code snippet in python, I tried running it but I am not able to understand the ouput that is being produced. Here is my code:

```
s = {"chris" :["1", "22", "333", "4444"] }
```

First For loop and it's output:

```
for i in range(len(s["chris"])):                     #10
      print(s["chris"][i])

Output: 
1
22
333
4444
```

Second For loop and it's output:

```
for i in range (len(s["chris"])):                    #7
      print(len(s["chris"][i]))

Output:
1
2
3
4
```

It would be a big help if someone could help me understand both the for loop codes and also help me underdstand the outputs produced. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it intuitive ?

Comment: Do you know what `range` and `len` do? If not, have you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: The first loop outputs the contents of the list one by one (in an extremely unpythonic, weird manner), the second one outputs the length of each string in that list - but again, nobody would do it like that. Is that an example you're supposed to be learning from?

Comment: Play around in a Python shell and see what `s["chris"]` produces, `s["chris"][0]`, `len(s["chris"])` and `list(range (len(s["chris"])))` (more helpful than `range(...)` alone here)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying. I am able to understand range and len. My problem is with understanding: print(s["chris"][i]) and print(len(s["chris"][i])). I am not exactly able to understand why the index i is used in both the places.

Comment: One resource I really like is http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html - that might help understanding what's happening.

Comment: @TheAsipiringone The usage of `i`, `range` and `len` here is a bit superfluous (and usually an anti-pattern in Python). The same output can be achieved with `for something in s["chris"]: print(something)` and `print(len(something))`

Comment: `len(dictionary)`? You never ask for the length of the dictionary. `len(s["chris"])` returns the number of elements in the list (4), and `len(s["chris"][i])` will return the number of characters of the string at index `i` in the list (1, 2, 3, and 4 respectively).

Answer (score 1):

**Explaination:**

First example:

- iterate trough the range of the dictionary's `chris` key ( `range` an iterator from `0` to `parameter - 1`)
- then get the value in the dictionary's `chris` key with that index

Second example:

- same as first example, but just getting length, so length of `'1'` is 1, and length of `'22'` is 2 and so on

Comment: Why would `range` mean `[1, 2, 3, 4]` ?

Comment: @DeepSpace Edited mine

Comment: It's still not accurate, `range(n)` returns an iterator (a list in Python 2 and a `range` object in Python 3) with the numbers `0` to `n - 1`.

Comment: @DeepSpace Now?

Answer (score 1):

You have a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) `s` and `"chris"` is the key pointing to the list `["1", "22", "333", "4444"]`. So calling `s["chris"]` gives you the list `["1", "22", "333", "4444"]`, while `s["chris"][i]`, for i =0, ... 3, gives you the elements of this list, i.e. `s["chris"][0] = "1"`, `s["chris"][1] = "22"`, etc. The rest you should figure out yourself.

Just let me add that the first loop is equivalent to

```
for val in s["chris"]:             
      print(val)
```

and the second loop to

```
for val in s["chris"]:             
      print(len(val))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `for i in range(some integer)` the loop will iterate i from 0 to that `some integer - 1`
for example following code will give `0 1 2 3 4` as output

```
for i in range(5):
    print (i)
```

in your first for loop you iterate `i` until 4 which is the length of list `"chris"` and you are printing the `i th` element in the `"chris"` list.So you get the first output

in the second loop, loop condition is same but there you printing the length of the `i th` element of `"chris"` list, which is  1 2 3 4 and that is your output in the second loop.

Hope you could understand